# Within extracting text from PDF to txt file the resulting txt file contains double quotes in some lines that I cannot get rid of

Tags: python, string, csv, pdf

When I try to extract text from a PDF to txt file in some cases some lines are clutched with double quotes "" for a reason I do not understand. The problem lies most likely in the way I process the text data, because I store it in a list before writing it.

I'd be very grateful for any help or idea what to do.

I use pdfplumber to extract the text pagewise from a pdf and split it into lines which are appended to a list that . However, some of the lines which are added as strings are added with single quotes e.g. 'Black -Hole – The Lost Transcript' and some with double quotes e.g. "Hi, I'm Varoujan Gorjian [...]."

Here is the first part of the list as extraction result of the PDF where strings are quoted in different signs:

> ['Black Hole – The Lost Transcript', 'Intro', "Hi, I'm Varoujan Gorjian, I'm a Research Astronomer at NASA's Jet Propulsion Laboratory.", "I've been challenged today to talk about once concept at five different levels of increasing", "complexity. Today we're going to be talking about black holes. A basic definition of a black", "hole is that it's a lot of mass crammed into a very tiny volume, such that the escaped", 'velocity is the speed of light.', 'Level 1 | 291 words (explainer: 221)', 'So, have you ever heard of something called a black hole?', ...]

Here is my code:
`for file in data:
path = os.path.join(dataDirectory, str(file))

```
    lines = []
    pdffile = path

    with pdfplumber.open(pdffile) as pdf:
        pages = pdf.pages
        for page in pdf.pages:
            text = page.extract_text()
            for line in text.split('\n'):
                lines.append(line)

    csvFile = os.path.join(goalDirectory, str(file)[:-3]+'txt')

    # open CSV file with coded Text
    with open(csvFile, "w", newline='', encoding='utf-8') as converted:
        writer = csv.writer(converted)
        print(lines)

        for line in lines:
            writer.writerow([line])`
```

What the PDF lookes like is this, so there are no double quotes and i want the plain text in the created txt-file:
[PDF of which text is extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDnn0.png)

Resulting txt file looks like this, where the double quotes in some lines are added:
[Text file with unwanted double quoutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBteL.png)

I've tried working with *quotechar* an *quoting* of the csv.writer method but couldn't come to a solution.

I probably need a solution that prevents strings from being clutched by double quotes within this block because some lines are (randomly) double quoted when added to "lines":

```
`with pdfplumber.open(pdffile) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for page in pdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            lines.append(line)`
```

Answer (score 1):

When extracting text  from OCR or other formats and using character seperated values, it would normally be seperated by line feeds \n

[image]

However in some cases such as here using `csv.writer` the separation may be by commas and thus existing `"strings with ,'s"` need protection from separation.

[image]

Think of it spread out before using comas as line feeds

```
Black Hole - The Lost Transcript

Intro

"Hi, I'm Varoujan Gorjian, I'm a Research Astronomer at NASA's Jet Propulsion Laboratory.",  
I've been challenged today to talk about once concept at five different levels of increasing,  
complexity. Today we're going to be talking about black holes. A basic definition of a black,  
"hole is that it's a lot of mass crammed into a very tiny volume, such that the escaped",  
velocity is the speed of light.,  

Level 1 | 291 words (explainer: 221)

"So, have you ever heard of something called a black hole?"

What is a black hole?

"Well, it has to do with, a lot with gravity, do you know what gravity is?"

"No, not at all."

It's what Keeps us on the earth.

What?

"The reason we're not just flying off the earth is because earth has gravity, so if we throw something up, it comes back down, so that's why when we're walking on the earth, we don't fly off the earth because the earth has gravity, and it keeps us down."

Nice.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, K J! It seems that you have a concrete idea of what is going wrong.
Can you maybe help me with my code what needs changing or how I can minimally adapt it for my purpose?

Comment: @Inhibitor_Aspirant, the solution seems to be not using a CSV file as you don't like what you see in the CSV file. If you only read the file back as CSV then it will just work (because the CSV reader will know what to do with the _escaping quotes_). It looks like you only have problems because you're looking at the file and don't like what you see; if you don't like what you see then I recommend that don't write it as CSV.

Comment: ... thanks alot Zach Young! That did the trick ... very simple and very good point.
I just changed it to:

    `csvFile = os.path.join(goalDirectory, str(file)[:-3]+'txt')
    with open(csvFile, 'w') as dataFile:
        for line in lines:
            dataFile.write(line+"\n")`